# How to set position of element equals to position of another element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The simple question. How to set position of element equals to position of another element by jquery or javascript?

The following code doesn't work:

```
$('#credit_tip').css('top', $('.credit').position().top);
$('#credit_tip').css('left', $('.credit').position().left);
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/position or http://api.jquery.com/offset then use http://api.jquery.com/css to position it absolutely.

Comment: This doesn't work as on code above.

Comment: In what way does it not work? Can you provide a ([minimal/representative](http://sscce.org)) [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/), and your HTML?

Comment: Full code available on the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800371/how-to-show-a-tip-on-a-proper-position-near-the-element

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TPyKS/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This helps me:

```
$('#credit_tip').css('top', $('.credit').offset().top);
$('#credit_tip').css('left', $('.credit').offset().left);
```

Answer (score 0):

See `left, top, bottom, right` these positons will only work if your specific element is `relatively` or `absolutely` positioned.

If your code is not affecting that way, then there is more possibilities that your div with id of `credit_tip` does not has a position of `relative` or `absolute`.

So what you can do is position the div to `relative` or `absolute` in `css`:

```
#credit_tip{
     position:relative;
 }
```

or with `jquery`:

```
$('#credit_tip').css({'top' : $('.credit').position().top, 
                      'left' : $('.credit').position().left,
                      'position':'relative'});
```

[See the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/PJB8N/)

and there might be possiblities that you are not calling jquery library in the document or might be some path error. So for this you can try `CDN Hosted` jQuery library.

[link to cdn host](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery)